# Error in creating a database dump on PostgreSQL

Tags: postgresql

When trying to make a PostgreSQL database dump we got the following error and the process stops immediately.

Command used:

```
openbravo@master.akluck.com:~

07/26 11:48:11> pg_dump -U tad -h localhost -p 5932 -F c -b -v -f /home/openbravo/dump26072018.dmp openbravo
```

Output:

```
pg_dump: reading schemas

pg_dump: reading user-defined tables

pg_dump: schema with OID 67046 does not exist

pg_dump: *** aborted because of error
```

Can you guide me to overcome this issue?

Answer (score 0):

In https://www.postgresql.org/message-id/20110215213337.GC95600%40mr-paradox.net the problem was solved by removing references to that schema from pg_class, pg_type and pg_constraint.